# How to lock navbar android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, navigationbar

i would like to know how I permanently block the android navigation bar. I use the Kotlin language and I need a function that when I enter the application, the standard Android navigation bar disappears and no longer appears, regardless of what I do within the application.

I found only codes that hide the slash, but it doesn't work for me. I need to block it so no one can access it as soon as it enters the app.

Comment: If you want kiosk-style behaviour you probably want *lock task mode*: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode . That requires setting the phone up as a *dedicated device* which can restrict things like app switching. Obviously, letting a random app lock the user out of the rest of their phone is a bad idea, so you can't do that without this kind of special setup

Comment: I am developing a drone app and the app cannot close at all while the person is flying the drone, ie using the app.

Comment: Whatever your reason is for wanting to do it, you can't - not on stock Android. *Immersive mode* (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive) is the best you can do, where the user can swipe the screen edges to access the nav bar etc. You can't prevent the user from navigating away from your app, for good reason. Your app should probably safely handle that kind of situation in `onStop` (e.g. putting the drone in a holding pattern) instead of relying on it being "impossible" (which would depend on the device OS, whether it's rooted, whether it's using a custom ROM, etc)